# Can I make it so that clicking radio buttons do not submit a form?

Tags: html, forms

This is my HTML:

```
<form class="form-signin" role="form" action="#" onclick="return signup(this);">
    <h2 class="form-signin-heading">Please sign up</h2>
    <input type="text" id="name" class="form-control" placeholder="Name" required autofocus>
    <input type="email" id="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email address" required>
    <input type="password" id="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" required>
    <input type="radio" name="member-type" value="student">Student</input> <br>
    <input type="radio" name="member-type" value="parent">Parent</input> <br>
    <input type="radio" name="member-type" value="alumnus">Alumnus</input> <br>
    <br>
    <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="button">Sign up</button>
</form>
```

When I click the radio buttons they submit the form. If I put the onclick inside of the button tag then I can no longer use "return signup(this);". Is there a workaround for either of these?

Comment: there are better ways to do what you need than to put an onclick handler in the form element that submits the form

Comment: Could you elaborate?

Comment: What does the `return signup(this)` do, and why do you think that you can't use it? Are you trying to submit the form with the button? Is there any reason why you don't use the `onsubmit` event of the form?

Comment: At the moment, clicking anywhere in the form element runs the `return signup(this)` code. The more sensible approach would be to add that code to the signup button. Please post your JS code as it should be possible to attach the signup code to that button instead.

Answer (score 0):

In your return signup function, return false if you do not want your form to submit.

If you do that, you can run specific validation your form. If you want the form to submit, simply return true in your function.

I would also change you button to type="submit" and your onClick parameter to onSubmit in your form tag.